# Redshift: serialization isolation violation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

1. process 1: insert & update(with subquery)
2. process 2: select & update
3. process 3: pure select

the violation error occurs in two places (table and process described below)

- somethings the process 1 might fail, then in order to fill the data ASAP, there will be multiple processes run at one time, then the process 2 (update data) will get `serialization isolation violation` with 3 transaction cycle, this can be explained, since this is possible: if the insert from process 1 happened after selection, and before update in process 2.
- the process 3 gets the same error `serialization isolation violation`

### Question

Why pure select gets isolation error in process 3?
The error begins in process 2, when the ETL process 1 finished, the error will disappear in both process 2 and process3.

### Table

table `data`:

```
id,time,company,info,count
```

### The Process

there are 3 process:

1: insert into `data`

we will insert the data into table from log data, update the count, the sql looks like this:

```
insert into data (time, company, info, count) values ('2023-08-01 00:00:00', 'A', '', 1);
update data set count = count where id in (select id from data where 
 ...);
```

this process is a ETL process written in java, run once per hour, as far as i know, `autocommit` is default `True`.

2: update `data`

we need to update the `info` field of the table, since the `info` are not present in ETL process, the process looks like this:

```
select id, company from data where date(time) = '2023-08-01' and info = '';
// do some calculation in python
update info = info where id = id;
commit;
```

this process using python with psycopg2 >= 2.7, besides `autocommit` is default value of `False`, run once per day.

3: query

we need to get the data for offline report, the sql:

```
select * from data where date(time) = '2023-08-01';

select count(*) from data where date(time) = '2023-08-01';

select company, count(company) from data where date(time) = '2023-08-01' group by company;
```

and this process using python with psycopg2 >= 2.7, `autocommit` is `False` by default.

### Code of Process 3

```py
conn = psycopg2.connect(config, connect_timeout=10)

def query(sql):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql)
    try:
        while True:
            rows = cur.fetchmany(1000)
            if not rows:
                break
            for row in rows:
                yield row
    except: # noqa
        pass
    cur.close()

def process(rows):
    for row in rows:
        pass

process(query("select * from data where date(time) = '2023-08-01'"))
process(query("select count(*) from data where date(time) = '2023-08-01'"))

conn.close()
```

Comment: you need to condense your question

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have some understanding of what is going on and how MVCC works so I'll go quickly past this.  However, you haven't provided enough information to know exactly what is going on but your question is about 'how it could happen' so a possible way is all you are looking for.

These serialization errors happen when at least 2 transactions create conflicting commit dependencies that cannot be resolved.  Redshift then needs to pick one (usually the one that commits first) to be committed and the other will be terminated and its updates lost.  From your description it looks like you have debugged this enough to think that process 1 (containing 2 transactions) is the one succeeding and process 2 (1 transaction) is being lost.  (Knowing exactly what is going on takes tracking the xids and oids involved and the exact timing of the statements in each transaction.)  You also state that these are separate "processes" which means that there are 3 separate connections to Redshift each with a unique PID (process id aka session).

Given this you ask 'why is the 3rd transaction failing?'.  It is likely that that source information of transaction 3 has been lost due to the serialization error.  But, you ask, 'if transaction 3 is read-only can can only use previously committed information how can this be?'.  It should have no dependency on uncommitted results which, I think, is the dilemma you are pointing to, no?

The first possibility is that transaction 3 isn't as "clean" as you think.  There are several ways this can happen:

1. Transaction 3 is in the same session as transaction #2.  Are these truly unique sessions?
2. There is some uncommitted information in transaction 3.  Is there
   connection pooling in play?  Does the python code run any SQL before
   this snippet that might not be committed?  Is this code being run
   from Lambda?
3. Transaction 3 is part of the loop.  What tables (objects) are referenced in transaction 3? Are these the serialization error table you expect?  Are there views involved that obscure the dependencies?

To know for sure what is happening you will need to list out all the statements for these 3 sessions.  Include the statement text, pid, xid, and exact time.  Highlight the xids and tables (oid) that are referenced in the error message.  Note when each transaction references these tables and when they are committed (you may need to align the commit system table with this info.  You are looking for when 2 transactions are trying to commit the same table but used different source information for calculating their update information.  This is a bit of a pain and I expect you will be surprised that one of these transactions has a lot more going on than you expect.

Once you understand the order of events I expect that the true reason for transaction 3 being terminated will be clear.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Here is the information: 1. these 3 process run in 3 different servers(AWS EC2), yes, they are true unique sessions; 2. transaction(process) 3 only have select statements, and there is no commit, i mean i never call the `.commit()`, and no connnection pool. 3. yes, the error `DETAIL: Serializable isolation violation on table - 206826` in process 2 & 3 ref to the same table, and there is no view in process 2

Comment: yes, if the error happened again, i know how to figure it out: what extactly happened in process 3. But for now, i can not reproduce the error of process 3 using concurrent transaction in redshift cli, only succeed for process 2 & 1.

Comment: OK.  It sounds like you are confirming that transactions 2 & 3 are both terminated due to the same serialization error.  Looking at the code you posted and wondering if there is more going on in this code.  What is reading the yielded rows?  How long does this take?  The catalog tables will be available for a few days after a serialization event so if the last one is more than a couple of days ago then it may take waiting for the issue to repeat (which may take a while since it is dependent on exact timing between these sessions).

Comment: the process 3 will read the data from redshift, then do some transform(filter out, transform format, calculation), finally it will write a report file, then the process ends.As for the session time, it is about 5 minutes at most. If the session got isolation error, the session time is about 5 seconds.

Comment: I think might be happening - 1) session 2 reads the table then after some code runs performs an update to the table while - 2) session 1 is running the update trans (update with sub-select). There is no serializable execution that can match what these concurrent transactions so one will be aborted. (no mystery here) Trans 3 is also running concurrently and also needs to produce a serializable result but this cannot be done - there is no serializable answer for all of this so trans 3 is aborted as well.  It's just a victim and being in flight for 5 sec increases the odds of being hit.

Comment: yes, this worth a trial with update & insert a lot of records. thanks for the anwser.